# Horizontal nav list overlapping with each other in chrome

Tags: html, css

If you look at it in Firefox everything is fine.

But in chrome the navigation overlaps.

If I change the font it works in chrome.

Any solution without changing the font?

This is the website bellow

http://www.arckai.com/samcode/

```
  <ul id="nav2">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>  

  #nav2 {
  float: right;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  font-size:100%
  }
  #nav2 ul li {


  }
  #nav2 li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: franchise;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-left: 0.7em;
  }
#nav2 a:link {
color: #FFFFFF;
outline: 0 none;
text-decoration: none;
}
#nav2 a:visited {
color: #FFFFFF;
}
#nav2 a:hover {
 color: #2F8FC4;
 transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
}
 #nav2 a:active {
 }
```

Comment: Hi & welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some code to illustrate your problem and perhaps an example on jsFidle.net. Also please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it. Do not provide code to the whole page, just enough to illustrate the problem. You may find the answer yourself by narrowing down the problem to a small section of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#nav2 li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: franchise;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-left: 0.7em;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ex9j2/8/)

Tested in IE11 and Chrome Version 32.0.1700.102

The problem is also with the font you have added check with that

Comment: Thanks, i'm suspecting the font is the problem aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article on [How To Use @FontFace](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/). Note the use of `format`. Change your @font-face declaration to:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "franchise";
    src: url("../Fonts/Franchise-Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

I haven't tested this but it *may* help